# Windows 10: Documents folder missing

Tags: windows, windows-10, sync, documents, user-folders

Whenever I log in to my computer I get a notification saying:

> A synced folder is missing
>
> Backup and Sync is trying to sync "Documents", but the folder has
>   either been moved or deleted.

Might I have deleted it by accident? is it just a case of me creating a new folder with the same name in the same location? I don't *think* there was anything in important in there but it would be good to fix the problem in order to stop the notification from appearing

Comment: There's a tutorial here (https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/23504-restore-default-location-personal-folders-windows-10-a.html) on how to restore your Documents (or any user folder) to its original location. Usually works on first attempt, provided there's no other issue with your system. You'll have to at least log off, preferably restart your PC. First boot may take a bit longer than usual. Disable Fast Boot in Power options before you restart.

Comment: If you open your Event Viewer you would probably find a _Known Folder_ error or warning, that in the folder of __C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile__ the know folders are missing. Simply goto the folder I mentioned and check if the folders exist. If not you can create them yourself.

Comment: Test the following two command in the **Explorer** Address bar to see if they rerference existing folders: `shell:personal` and `shell:local documents`.